# How can I copy over all weights and trees from xgboost.spark.SparkXGBClassifier to xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn, xgboost

Long story short, I trained an xgboost classifier model in Spark using **xgboost.spark.SparkXGBClassifier**:

```
from xgboost.spark import SparkXGBClassifier

spark_xgboost_classifier = SparkXGBClassifier (
  features_col=numeric_features,
  label_col=target,
  num_workers=1,
  missing=0.0,
  max_depth=5,
  use_gpu=True
)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[spark_xgboost_classifier])

model = pipeline.fit(train.limit(2500000))

model.stages[0].save('model.json')
```

I want to be able to use the python package **explainerdashboard** but it requires the sklearn wrapper:  **xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier** (according to an error I had when attempting to use the booster directly).

So now I'm wondering, do I have to train a new model? Can I just load the model using the json file directly onto **xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier**? Do I need to copy over all the weights and parameters and trees? Just very confused about where to go from here.

1. I tried using the booster:

```
model.stages[0].get_booster()

booster: xgb.Booster = model.stages[0].get_booster()

explainer = explainerdashboard.ClassifierExplainer(booster, test.select(numeric_features).limit(10000).toPandas(), test.limit(50000).select(target).toPandas())
```

but it raised the error:
`ValueError: For xgboost models, currently only the scikit-learn compatible wrappers xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier and xgboost.sklearn.XGBRegressor are supported, so please use those instead of xgboost.Booster!`

2. I then tried to just load from the saved json file but I can't actually load the model:

```
sklearn_model = xgb.sklearn.XGBClassifier( features_col=numeric_features,
  label_col=target,
  missing=0.0,
  max_depth=5
)

sklearn_model.load_model('model.json')
```

but it gave me a strange unintelligible error which seems to have an issue reading from s3? I am so lost!!!

```
XGBoostError: [16:18:03] ../dmlc-core/src/io.cc:69: unknown filesystem protocol s3a://
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x811ad5) [0x7fc537611ad5]
  [bt] (1) /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x811cdb) [0x7fc537611cdb]
  [bt] (2) /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x811ee5) [0x7fc537611ee5]
  [bt] (3) /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x1947d9) [0x7fc536f947d9]
  [bt] (4) /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x144770) [0x7fc536f44770]
  [bt] (5) /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(XGBoosterLoadModel+0x185) [0x7fc536f44b55]
  [bt] (6) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8(+0x7e2e) [0x7fc5d3e10e2e]
  [bt] (7) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8(+0x4493) [0x7fc5d3e0d493]
  [bt] (8) /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0xa3e9) [0x7fc5d050b3e9]
```

Comment: In the end, I did the following to get it to work (had to save the booster, model file wouldn't work for me for some reason):\


`booster_: xgb.Booster = model.get_booster()`\
`booster_.save_model('{}/model/booster/booster.json'.format(local_path))`\
`sklearn_model = xgb.sklearn.XGBClassifier(features_col=numeric_features, label_col=target, missing=0.0, max_depth=5)`\
`sklearn_model.load_model('{}/model/booster/booster.json'.format(local_path))`